# Extjs Create New Browser

Tags: extjs, drag-and-drop

I am using Extjs4.0 to develop a web application. The application require drag a Extjs Panel outside current browser. Then create a new browser instance which has the panel object.

I did some research. Javascript has window.open function which can create a new window. But how can I pass the panel parameters to the new browser instance?

Does any one have relative experiences? or have some suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try [GreyBox](http://orangoo.com/labs/GreyBox/)

**Note** :- Sometime it breaks if there is an error in page
for e.g. it fails to open SO
but it works fine otherway

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible. You are asking if you can **drag** an ExtJS Panel outside the Browser itself? Think about it, you can't do that.

You *can* open a new Window with ExtJS content, sure.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It uses window.open command to create a new browser with parameters. It works. Thks.